# uncertainty about some uses of motion verbs

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, вид, глаголы-движения

I did a proficiency test recently and I wanted to clarify why I got some answers wrong. In the following examples:

"Летом мы **ездим** на дачу каждые выходные." -- It's "ездим" / ездить because it's done *usually* ?

"Завтра мы **поедем** в Академгородок на маршрутке №15. -- It's "поедем" because it's *specific* ?

"Та женщина, **которой** ты дал 100 рублей, где она сейчас? -- It's "которой" because it answers the question "кому" but the female form? (I had answered "которому.")

"Мне не **поднять** этот пакет. Помогите, пожалуйста."  Why is this "поднять" and not "поднимать" ?

"Ребенок заплакал, *так как испугался*." It could also be "испугавшись" because it's past perfect?

"Приглашения удалось получить **тем**, кто подал заявки заранее." It's "тем" because it answers the question "кому" ?

благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ‘Yes’ to all of your yes/no questions, with one little remark: a subordinate clause *кото́рой ты́ да́л сто́ рубле́й* answers the question *‘како́й [же́нщине]?’* or *‘кото́рой [же́нщине]?’*, not *‘кому́?’*.
- *Подня́ть* (i. e. perfective aspect) rather *поднима́ть* (imperfective) is because he can not *carry out* an action – lifting a bag.

  (Although that is not the thing, you have to know at your level of Russian, *Мне́ не поднима́ть э́тот паке́т* is a pretentious way to say “I’m not going to lift the bag”. I doubt that anyone would ever say this very sentence, but something like *мне́ с ни́м не жи́ть* “I’m not going to live with him” is somewhat common colloquial expression, which implies “I don’t care of his merits / demerits”.)
- It could be *Ребёнок запла́кал, испуга́вшись*, but in this case there would not be a semantic stress on cause. So it would not fit well as an answer to a ‘Why?’ question “*Почему́ запла́кал ребёнок?*”.

Comment: so, so helpful, mucho appreciado.

Comment: @новичок Нема за що. Even though, as your are new to StackExchange, I would remind you that it’s highly desirable [to mark the question solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it have been solved.

Comment: Dmitry thank you I was not aware, I think I marked it as such now, thank you! zapomniu!